# How to combine two integer vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm wondering how to combine two integer like this

```
vector <int>  A = {3,4,5};
vector <int>  B = {100,102,103};
```

and then can we have a fast way or a funtion that can help to attach the vector B to vector A and vector A then look like this :

```
A = { 3,4,5,100,102,103}
```

Comment: ``vec1.insert(vec1.begin(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end())``

Comment: If you just want to append `B` to `A` and not want `A` to be sorted at the end, you can use STL `std::copy` algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using insert of c++

```
A.insert(A.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

[There are further more ways to do that find it here :](https://www.techiedelight.com/concatenate-two-vectors-cpp/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector::insert`:

```
std::vector<int> A { 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> B { 100, 102, 103 };
A.insert(A.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```